# How to capture email address in app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gae-userservice

I have created an application in app engine for our company. Only the domain users can access the application .How can i capture the email address in Google App Engine without any authentication ? I tried to capture the email address on application using

```
   UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
   currentUser=userService.getCurrentUser();
```

but it shows a popup saying that your email address will be captured. I don't want to confuse the domain users with that popup. In App script  it simply captures the email address using

```
var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
Logger.log(email);
```

Is there any way to bypass the authentication popup for my domain users accessing the webapp ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. That's the whole point of authentication: user has to give your app permission to access certain data in their profile (including email).

Comment: Thanks for the Suggestion Peter .What is the best practice to capture email address on App engine form ?

Comment: We can do it with UserServices the code will only work if we execute it on a subdomain.